# Convert string date to unix time

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have problem to convert string of data to unix time

my script:

```
import datetime


s="2018-06-29 08:15:27"

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(type(date_time_obj))

datetime.timestamp(date_time_obj)
```

and I have this error:

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'timestamp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timestamp` is a method on the `datetime` class, not the module itself. Just do:

```
date_time_obj.timestamp()
```

Or alternatively:

```
datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_time_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `timestamp` method of the `datetime` class inside the `datetime` module:

```
datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_time_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_time_obj)
```

This should work since you will be using the module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime  # pep8 import style

s = "2018-06-29 08:15:27"
unix_stamp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output

> 1530252927.0

Another answer mentioned using `.timestamp` in `date` object.